# Windows - Stop killing my Terminals for an update

Tags: windows-store-app, windows-terminal

I am using and really enjoying the [WindowsTerminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). I find it to be a big improvement over conhost, and most of the alternatives. With one exception.

Whenever Microsoft releases an update, the update automatic is applied and kills all my currently running terminals and anything running in them. This is getting really frustrating and has destroyed in-progress work.

I know I could completely disable automatic updates for all store apps, but this seems like such an poor option. Is there any other method to prevent the update process from just killing off my terminals whenever Microsoft thinks it should be updated?

Comment: Looking at the release history, the only version of Windows Terminal that is updated more than once every 60 days, is Windows Terminal Preview.  My suggestion is switch all your UWP applications to update when you initiate the update, this way you can control when they are updated.  Being updated through Windows Store is one of the things you have to accept if you want to use a UWP based application. Since Windows Terminal is a feature of Windows 11, when it's updated, will likely be slightly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is discussed in the issue report from December 2019
[Terminal windows are closed whenever updated from the store #3915](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3915).

The answer by Microsoft was that fixing the problem requires
an agreement between the Windows Terminal team and the Store team,
which apparently is not happening. The post itself was locked
because "isn't value in leaving it unlocked for angry people to get
their digs in".

A Microsoft developer offered a workaround, which is not to install
Windows Terminal from the Store.

His idea is to:

- Uninstall Windows Terminal from the Store
- Download the Windows Terminal release from
  [github](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases)
- Use 7Zip to unpack the `.msixbundle` file and then the file
  `CascadiaPackage_*.0_x64.msix`
- Find and extract `WindowsTerminal.exe`
- Run directly the `.exe`.

Read the issue report for comments about this workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Annoyed there isn't a fix, but it is what it is.